# I have MEAN stack connected to mlab, how should I host it on web with domain xxxx.ga?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, web-hosting, shared-hosting

Please explain as simple as you can, since Heroku has its own domain. I need xxxx.ga as name of my domain connected to mlab. How can I achieve this?
Free hosting like hostfree.pw don't work I understand as it doesn't provide us with access to shell command.

Comment: Are you willing to spare a few bucks or need it free?

Comment: Accept answer if found useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your application is already deployed on Heroku,

the following documentation can be used to register a custom domain and direct it to the same app deployed on heroku.

[Custom Domain for Heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Also, you can try another hosting platform similar to Heroku- 
[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have already deployed on heroku, Now your answer has helped me a bit thanks